# How to compress downloaded images and decompress when needed in Android?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout

How to compress jpg/bmp files which I can store in the memory then when needed decompress those images and show to users without losing too much of image quality? How to do the compress and decompress, any guidance/ link would be helpful.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

create image thumbnails

'byte[] imageData = null;

```
    try     
    {

        final int THUMBNAIL_SIZE = 64;

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);
        Bitmap imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);

        imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, THUMBNAIL_SIZE, false);

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        imageData = baos.toByteArray();

    }
    catch(Exception ex) {

    }`
```

Comment: Thanx @Amit pandey

Answer (score 0):

if u need for thumbNail then use 
ThumbNailUtils.extractThumbnail(Bitmap source,int width,int height)
it show thumbnail from bitmap and when u want to show original bitmap then show bitmap
.
 use wisely bitmap object cause it take more memory at runtime.

Comment: Hey thanx @ankitsinh corepix for the help with thumbnails but when using bitmaps is there any compression and decompression so that it takes less space?

Comment: yes u can see in Android documentation or see in Below Link it's for compression      https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap#java              for decompression u have to use bitmap uri which directly load bitmap     if u like then thumbs up answer.